# How do I count matches in two columns (same row) based on a third column criteria in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns of data: Week, Winner, and Prediction. I have figured out how to count matches in the two columns (Winner and Prediction) if they match on the same row. I would now like to add the condition to count these if Week is equal to 0,1,2,...

Example Data:

```
Week Winner Predictions
0 TeamA TeamA
1 TeamA TeamB
1 TeamC TeamC
1 TeamD TeamE
2 TeamA TeamA
2 TeamC TeamD
2 TeamE TeamE
3 TeamA TeamD
3 TeamB TeamB
3 TeamE TeamE
```

etc...

I would like to create weekly standings to see how the Predictions compare to the Winners. Overall I have found that **=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B11=C2:C11))** gives me the number of matches and **=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B11=B2:B11))** gives me the number of non-matches. Now I would like to condition this based on the weeks. Thanks in advance, I've been struggling through every possible combination of IF, COUNTIFS, and SUMPRODUCT and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Please include desired results.

Comment: How do you figure that `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B11=B2:B11))` would return the number of non-matches when you haven't included the 2nd column in the formula?

Comment: In Column D, for matched, try `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$11=$C$2:$C$11)*(A2=$A$2:$A$11))`. In Column E, for unmatched, try `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$11<>$C$2:$C$11)*(A2=$A$2:$A$11))`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a helper column that identifies the correct picks and then thrown this into a Pivot Table?

Answer (score 0):

You do not make clear how you want to present your counts by week number of correct and incorrect predictions (matches and non-matches in your terminology).

One possibility is to create a separate list which identifies, for each week, the number of correct and incorrect predictions. This avoids the clunkiness of repeating weekly results in column D or reporting against just the first (or last) occurrence of a week number in column A.

Starting this separate list in cell `E1` and putting the week numbers in cells `E2`, `E3`,etc, then a suitable formula for cell `F2` to count the number of correct predictions is
`=SUM(($B$2:$B$11=$C$2:$C$11)*($E2=$A$2:$A$11))`
A slightly edited version of this for the number of incorrect predictions in cell `G2` is
`=SUM(($B$2:$B$11<>$C$2:$C$11)*($E2=$A$2:$A$11))`

These formulae can be copied to subsequent rows of columns `F` and `G` to complete the second list. Note the use of relative and absolute addressing (the $ signs) means that the formula in `F2` can be copied to `G2` and the only edit required will be changing the (second) equals sign (`=`) to not equals (`<>`).

[image: Screenshot]

In Excel the boolean values of `TRUE` and `FALSE` can be coerced into taking the integer values of `1` and `0`, respectively, by applying an arithmetic operation. One common way of doing this (as you have used in your OP) is double negation. Another way is to multiply by 1. A third way, used in the formulae above and as suggested earlier in a comment by @bugdrown, is to multiply two booleans together. The formulae above also use the simpler function `SUM` instead of  `SUMPRODUCT` (though, in this particular case, either can be used).

If you are using a version of Excel which utilises [dynamic arrays](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-dynamic-arrays-functions-formulas/) then the list of week numbers in column `E` can be dynamically generated from column `A` using the`UNIQUE` function by entering `=UNIQUE(A2:A11)` as the formula in cell `E2`. With a version which does not support dynamic arrays, you will need to find another way of creating the unique list of week numbers.